# SQL Server - Selecting multiple maximum values matching two separate corresponding cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in SQL and been trying to obtain all of the maximum values as per the access strength and folder names, with allowing groups to the folders being displayed accordingly. I tried using MAX function but it was returning only 1 maximum result. Thank you in advance for any help or guidance of how t achieve the specified results.

Please see the jpg link attached for the top table and the desired outcome in the bottom table.

John

[image: top table and the desired outcome in the bottom table]

Comment: Are you looking for a limited number of entries or will that change?

Comment: You should paste your sample text into your question instead of using a screen shot.  Also, while it's easy to assume what you've tried via `MAX()` you should paste your attempts into your question as well.  Both of those things give people a better starting place for answering your question.  To format the chunks that you paste in, highlight them and click the `{}` button (code sample).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function to put your records in an order, then select only the top 1:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Folder_name,
            [User],
            Access,
            Group_Allowing,
            [Rank] = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Folder_Name, [User] ORDER BY Access DESC)
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  Folder_name,
        [User],
        Access,
        Group_Allowing
FROM    CTE
WHERE   [Rank] = 1;
```

The `PARTITION BY` clause is similar to GROUP BY, and the ranking will start again at 0 for each group. The order by simply then indicates what order to do the ranking in.

Comment: +1, Best answer to this direct question, and also to many similar SQL questions here. OP and others: You won't regret a second spent learning RANK, ROW_NUMBER, and friends.

Comment: @MattStephenson Assuming SQL Server 2005+, not an unreasonable assumption, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put your query using `MAX()` into a subquery and `JOIN` to it:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM YourTable a
JOIN (SELECT Folder_Name, [User], MAX(Access) Max_Access
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY Folder_Name, [User]
     )b
 ON a.Folder_Name = b.Folder_Name
  AND a.[User] = b.[User]
  AND a.Access = b.Max_Access
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ORDER BY Access DESC" and "LIMIT [number of entries you want]" or if you want to just get the highest number you can use "GROUP BY Access" and then use max() to display all the entries you want

Comment: SQL-Server uses `SELECT TOP n [percent]`, and not `LIMIT`